# SQL Data Grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server

I was hoping someone would be able to help me (or point me in the right direction) on the following problem. I'm looking at grouping a large number of codes to only 3 digits, ensuring that if a participant had the code 122.2 and 122.3, it would count as one occurrence and not two.

Data Example:

```
Participant | group_code
1           | 1223
1           | 1224
1           | 1123
2           | 1012
2           | 0123
```

Current Code:

```
SELECT  (left(group_code, 3)) as Group, count(left(group_code, 3)) as occurrence 
from testDB
group by left(group_code, 3)
```

I suspect I need to use a unique element on the participant ID when grouping, however I'm not too sure.

Current Outcome:

Using the current data example, the result is as follows.
122 has 2 occurrences 
112 has 1 occurrence
101 has 1 occurrence
012 has 1 occurrence

Expected Outcome:

122 has 1 occurrences 
112 has 1 occurrence
101 has 1 occurrence
012 has 1 occurrence

Question: Is it possible to change the current code so that, if a single participant has multiple occurrences of a 3 digit value, for example 111.1, 111.2, 111.3, and 111.4, using the code above would provide the out 111 has occurred 4 times. However, I only want it to state it has appeared once as I'm only interested in a 3 digit level (and not the 4th).

Many thanks

Comment: if 122.2,122.4 it should show as 122

Comment: Did you try [ROUND](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx)

Comment: It would potentially be Floor or Ceiling opposed to Round, can you post the expected output please, its still not entirely clear what you are looking to get. The test talks about 122.3 but the example given is just 1223, no decimal.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server?

Comment: The question makes no sense. Just group by left(3) and select 1 as Occurence...Here is your query: `SELECT  (left(group_code, 3)) as Group, 1 as occurrence 
from testDB
group by left(group_code, 3)`

Comment: check my answer, which exactly you want. tell me if any thing you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
declare @t table ( group_code varchar(15))

insert into @t values ('122.2') ,('122.3' ) ,( '122.4' ) ,( '112.6'),( '112.0') , ( '119.1')

   SELECT  (left(group_code, 3)) as Grop, 
        count(left(group_code, 3)) as occurrence 
    from @t
        group by left(group_code, 3) 

select * from
(

    SELECT  (left(group_code, 3)) as Grop, 
        count(left(group_code, 3)) as occurrence 
    from @t
        group by left(group_code, 3) 
) a
join @t t on a.Grop  = left(t.group_code, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Create Table #T(Id int, Value decimal(16,2))

Insert into #T
Values(1,122.2),(1,122.3),(2,122.2)


Select Id,ROUND(Value,0)
from #T
Group By Id,ROUND(Value,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT  (left(group_code, 3)) as Group, count(*) as occurrence 
from testDB
group by left(group_code, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

According to your last edit in your question it should be this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Participant INT, group_code INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,1223)
,(1,1224)
,(1,1123)
,(2,1012)
,(3,0123);

WITH WithGroupingNew AS
(
    SELECT tbl.*
          ,LEFT(CAST(tbl.group_code AS varchar(100)),3) AS NewGroupingCode
    FROM @tbl AS tbl
)
,Counted AS
(
    SELECT *
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NewGroupingCode ORDER BY group_code) AS Counter
    FROM WithGroupingNew
)
SELECT *
FROM Counted 
WHERE Counter=1
```

This as before the edit, might be useful though...

With this CTE you get a field with the information you need:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Participant INT, group_code INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,1223)
,(1,1224)
,(1,1123)
,(2,1012)
,(3,0123);

WITH WithGroupingNew AS
(
    SELECT tbl.*
          ,LEFT(CAST(tbl.group_code AS varchar(100)),3) AS NewGroupingCode
    FROM @tbl AS tbl
)
SELECT * FROM WithGroupingNew
```

Result

```
Participant group_code  NewGroupingCode
1           1223        122
1           1224        122
1           1123        112
2           1012        101
3           0123        123
```

It's on you to decide, what you are going to do with this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT NewGroupingCode FROM WithGroupingNew
```

or maybe

```
SELECT DISTINCT Participant,NewGroupingCode FROM WithGroupingNew
```

or maybe

```
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY NewGroupingCode ORDER BY group_code)
```